# Getting sum of an string array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a text file:

```
2|BATH BENCH|19.00
20312100000|ORANGE BELL|1.42
04525514840|BOILER ONION|1.78
```

I need to find the summation of the price which is `(19.00,1.42,1.78)` and print it in the console.

```js
var FilePath = process.argv[2];
var allUpcs = [];
var subtotal = 0;

const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const file = readline.createInterface({
input: fs.createReadStream(FilePath),
output: process.stdout,
terminal: false
});

file.on('line', (line) => {
allUpcs.push(line.split('|')[2]).map(Number);

var subtotal = allUpcs.reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);
});

file.on('close', function() {
console.log(subtotal = allUpcs.reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0));
});
```

I am not getting the correct output, getting it as `Subtotal 019.001.421.78`.

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: You should be getting errors because of `allUpcs.push(line.split('|')[2]).map(Number);` the `push()` method returns *a number* (the new length of the array), so there is no `.map()` method on it.

Comment: The subtotal calculations in the line event handler are not being used. You can remove them. Only the one in the close handler matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the result of the `map` anywhere, so you're still just pushing a string into the array, then discarding the result of `map`.

Use this instead:

```
allUpcs.push(parseFloat(line.split('|')[2]));
```